# Vector space an linear independence

Tags: vector-spaces

if vectors space $S$ contains vector $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ over $F_2$
and vector space $Z$ contains vectro $(1,0),(0,0)$ ,then can we say $$S\not\in Z$$ but $$Z\in S.$$
Anather Question ,Over $F_2$ thos Vectors $v_1=(1,0),v_2=(0,1),v_3=(1,1)$ are linearly independent or linearly dependent ?
Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ and $Z$ are both vector spaces, I don't think $\notin$ is the right notation. I think what you intend to say is subspace or subset.

We just know that $Z$ contain $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$. However, $Z$ might also contains exactly the same vector as $S$. Unless you know that it only contain exactly those two vectors, then $S$ is clearly not a subspace of $Z$.

$Z$ is a subspace of $S$.

Since $v_1+v_2+v_3=0$, they are linearly dependent.